# lazy loading angular pagination

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Сделал разбивку на страницы по инструкции в этой ссылке
[Ссылка](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)

Постраничная разбивка работает, но вначале идет загрузка всех данных, а потом разбивка на страницы. Как сделать ленивую загрузку, чтобы данные подгружались с сервера при смене страницы ?

Участок из вью

```
 <tr dir-paginate="item in model.items | itemsPerPage: 10">{{ item }} 
                    <td>{{item.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.campaign}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.state}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.app}}</td>
...

<dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true">
            </dir-pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описание, как сделать асинхронную загрузку данных описано в [документации](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#working-with-asynchronous-data), которую Вы привели в вопросе.

Пример.

```
.controller('UsersController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.users = [];
$scope.totalUsers = 0;
$scope.usersPerPage = 25; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page
getResultsPage(1);

$scope.pagination = {
    current: 1
};

$scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
    getResultsPage(newPage);
};

function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {
    // this is just an example, in reality this stuff should be in a service
    $http.get('path/to/api/users?page=' + pageNumber)
        .then(function(result) {
            $scope.users = result.data.Items;
            $scope.totalUsers = result.data.Count
        });
}
})

<div ng-controller="UsersController">
<table>
    <tr dir-paginate="user in users | itemsPerPage: usersPerPage" total-items="totalUsers" current-page="pagination.current">
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

HTML шаблон.

```
<dir-pagination-controls on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
```